# How can I enforce that enum constants must be uppercase in Checkstyle?

Tags: java, enums, checkstyle

Suppose I have the following enum:

```
enum Colour
{
    RED   (1),
    GREEN (2),
    Blue  (3); // Invalid

    final int colourCode;

    Colour(final int code)
    {
        this.colourCode = code;
    }
}
```

I want Checkstyle to enforce that all of the enum constants must only contain uppercase characters, digits and underscores.

In this case `Blue` should throw an error, while everything else (including the member `colourCode`) is okay.

I've had a look at `MemberName`, `ConstantName` and `StaticVariableName` from [the naming section of the documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html) but none seem to apply, nor are you able to target them specifically at enums.

Comment: With regular expressions like `/[A-Z]+/`

Comment: Doesn't ConstantName apply to enum as well? At least, that would surprise me.

Comment: @laune It doesn't and it surprised me too. My ConstantName rule works correctly on static final fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Checkstyle cannot do that out-of-the-box, surprisingly. You'll have to use the [Sevntu Checkstyle](http://sevntu-checkstyle.github.io/sevntu.checkstyle/) addon, which features the [EnumValueNameCheck](http://sevntu-checkstyle.github.io/sevntu.checkstyle/apidocs/index.html?com/github/sevntu/checkstyle/checks/naming/EnumValueNameCheck.html). I think the default behavior is just what you need, so you'd configure it thusly:

```xml
<module name="EnumValueName"/>
```

Be sure to add Sevntu Checkstyle to your Checkstyle classpath before running it. Their website has descriptions on how to do that in various scenarios.